# Tips for golfing in Arn

Tags: code-golf, tips

Does anyone have tips on how to golf in this language? Please one tip per answer and avoid posting simple and general tips such as "remove whitespace".

[Here](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) is the github link and [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Arn) is the esolang page.

Comment: By the way, there is a short list of tips [here](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Syntax#tips-for-golfing).